# Difference between IEEE 802.11ah and IEEE 802.16

Tags: ieee-802.11

What is the difference between IEEE 802.11ah (HaLow) and IEEE 802.16 (WiMax).
They both run using low frequencies. Is the only difference the methods for modulation (?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: 802.16 is a series of standards for mid-range metro wireless networks, mainly for backhaul or device-to-device communication. 802.11ah instead, is a standard for low-power, low frequencie ap-to-enddevice communication in home automation or intra device communication for industrial machines.

The long answer can be found by reading the standard(s) and/or the wikipedia articles for it ;)